NIC intermittently receiving many duplicate TCP ACKs?
I have been having intermittent spikes in response time with HTTP(S) traffic on WiFi that last varying amounts of time. (Or at the very least HTTP(S) traffic, I do not notice it with Spotify's audio for example.) This has only been happening since I moved from Debian 11 to Debian 12, though I cannot pinpoint when exactly it started after doing that. (I also set up a new router within this time frame, so maybe that could be related?)
It also only seems to happen after my machine has been on for some time.
I ran Wireshark while it was happening and noticed that my machine was receiving a lot of duplicate TCP ACK segments, and to a lesser extent, RST segments.
None of the other devices on my network have this issue, I am also dual-booted with Windows 10 and have no issues. This leads me to believe there is something up with the wireless network drivers (I have an AX200 NIC) or there is some network-related software that is mucking things up.
Any tips on further troubleshooting/solutions?

It's normal to have a certain amount of duplicate TCP ACK events, but they can indicate various issues in high numbers. You'll need to rule out more possible issues. For example, try connecting over ethernet for a while (if possible). Try monitoring traffic to other devices on your local network - If you still see intermittent issues there, then wifi/driver problems are more likely. If not, then your router/internet service may be more at fault.

While I haven't monitored traffic on other devices, I can definitely tell that this issue is very much limited to my Debian install. (The webpages failing to load are very noticeable.) I did find this forum post which seemed to describe a similar issue. I might try looking at that again to see if I missed something the first time I looked for conflicting networking services.
Otherwise as you mentioned, probably a driver issue.

Please check log of your wireless driver/AP look for association/disassotiation events channel hoping etc. Try to switch driver version. Check WiFi client setting that they compatible with access point. Try to switch WiFi channels - maybe on you channel there is periodic noise from some appliance.

@Nikolai Tried searching Google for where I can find logs for my wireless adapter and I'm not seeing any on my machine. Seems like Linux-related info on AX200 NICs and their drivers is a bit sparse/hard to find.
As far as I can tell, this issue is contained to this singular Debian install, so I shouldn't need to mess around with my router at all.

Did you also run Wireshark when booted from Windows? If you skipped that step because Windows didn't show the original problem symptoms, then the duplicate Acks you saw might be a red herring. Correlation does not imply causation.
Also the "a lot" anecdote is not a meaningful data point. It needs to be quantified into a rate, perhaps like "duplicate Acks received per TCP segment sent" on a single TCP connection. If you're sending out many thousands of TCP segments per second, a Wireshark-screenful of incoming duplicate Acks might feel like "a lot", but may only be a measly 0.1%.

@Spiff The same amount did not seem to appear on Windows, and when the slow loading issue is not happening, it seems like there are not as many on Debian as well. My wireshark skills are a bit lacking so I'm having a difficult time trying to a provide a better quantifier than "a lot". (As well as properly following the flow here.)

I still do not know what the exact cause was, but since I have recently moved to a new place I am no longer experiencing the issue. (I made no further configuration changes since my last comment, and the router and NIC are the same ones.)
Things that I can think of that might have had an impact:

New modem/switching from cable to fiber (I wouldn't think this would have changed anything.)
Router having been power cycled
Antenna for NIC was detached and re-attached
Updates to my installed packages (E.g. If it was just a Firefox issue.)

